# SMTP standards for invalid email address (when multiple addresses used)

Tags: email, smtp

I thought this would be better on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1026599/default-smtp-functionality-if-one-of-multiple-addresses-is-invalid), but it appears that is not the case - however, I'm not sure this is a good fit for Stackoverflow either.  So I'll ask it here anyway...

Is there default functionality (or recognised standards) across SMTP relays as how they deal with a single email that has multiple addresses, where one or more of the address is invalid?

In my testing it appears that if the SMTP detects an invalid address (normally because there is no corresponding address in the corporate SMTP system I'm connecting to) then the entire email fails - nobody on the email receives it.

Can anybody confirm if this is standard functionality?

Or is it something that can be configured at an individual SMTP level?

Or is it down to the individual SMTP vendor to decide how it deals with emails where one or more addresses are invalid?

**Is it ever possible that the "other" recipients would still get the email?**

Notes...

- I am a programmer, not a network administrator, so I have literally no experience of setting up or configuring SMTP relays.  But I need to know how to handle those errors in my code should the SMTP I'm connected to come back with an issue.
- This is not specific to a particular SMTP vendor, as my application must run against any SMTP relay that our client desires.

Comment: AFAIK the mail sender will send multiple emails, one per recipient. If you didn't do that, any BCC headers would be sent to everybody, defeating the purpose. If your SMTP software doesn't do that automatically, maybe you need to send the email for each recipient.

Comment: Thanks @Robert - the entire point of the BCC was so that my software could send a single message to the SMTP for a large quantity of recipients. If I send them individually (as I currently do) we're hitting timeout issues where the ASP.Net request is being terminated before all emails have gone out. Ideally all SMTPs (as default) will fail to send the email, so nobody gets it - rather than finding that a sub-set of them did, and then having to figure out who got it and who didn't

Comment: The RFCs say that once a mail server accepts the email it must either deliver or bounce it. Most mailers will keep retrying (for days) on temporary failures, so you can never know that everybody got the email until you got the "success" delivery status notification (DSN). You may need to explicitly request a DSN for success. Even when an email is delivered, it may end up in the spam folder. Non-conformant mail servers may accept emails and still lose them (when they crash) or silently discard them (considered spam). DSNs also don't guarantee everybody got it. Email is just not made for this.